# where to source images for Label makers or general images

Tags: image

I'm not an artist and do not have much time to spend on design in general.  I have the need for a royalty free image of a Label/tag/maybe printer.  I tried a few sites on google, but most seem to have some kind of fee attached to them...only to be revealed after a few button clicks.

Where can I find royalty free images for an intranet website?  No fees or hidden charges please.

Comment: I know I provided an answer, but this really is not on topic for this site. This is a site for user experience questions, not graphic design questions.

Comment: @Charles Boyung - hm, ok...I saw http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22803/web-design and this site looked to be the closest to the question that I was able to find on SE.  Thanks for the feedback and answer.

Comment: Interesting - they're a little broad on where they recommend people go for those question types. Anyways, another option if you don't find what you need from us is http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ - they might have some more resources for you.

Comment: @Charles Boyung - Nice, that one looks promising for these kinds of issues.  Thanks again

Comment: In fact, they already have a good list of places to find royalty-free images. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-free-stock-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://iconfinder.net

You can filter results by license to only show royalty free commercially licensed images.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual Studio, chances are there's already a nice free image library on your hard drive:
[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/tips-and-tricks-visual-studio-2010-image-library/)